# Can someone confirm my derivation of the generalized power law from Practical Electronics, 4th edition?

Tags: power, theory, formula-derivation

[image]

I dont know how to use LaTeX, so I used Mathcha and took a snip from there.

Comment: Well if your derivation were wrong, you would have ended up with something other than P = VI.

Comment: I wanted to confirm if the steps are logical.